# How to rapidly switch between two desktop settings?

Tags: windows-7, display

Is there some way to set up shortcuts to easily switch between having two monitors extended or duplicated simply?  Perhaps a powershell script that would set it to one and another powershell script that would set it to the other settings?

(My motivation is that when I am working alone I want the monitors set to extended to be able to use them both effectively, but sometimes when collaborating or displaying something it is convenient to have the display duplicated.  Since I go back and forth, frequently, I would like a shortcut to make the change, rather than going through the Screen resolution menu in Windows 7 every time.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In windows 7, you can hit the windows key + p to launch the screen menu:
[image: Windows Monitor selection menu]

If you are using a laptop, a lot of laptops have shortcut keys that will launch this menu, on thinkpads, it is Fn + F7.
This menu uses whatever settings, as far as resolutions, that you have set in the Screen Resolution menu.